# HTML view google calendar in outlook

Tags: html, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a google calendar which I've shared with my Microsoft Outlook client via the  iCal format link.  It is imported as an internet calendar in my Outlook.  All events are viewable, but any of the events which contain HTML code show up in Outlook as NOT HTML.

example:

This is a test of ***HTML*** format

Shows up in Outlook as:

```
This is a test of <b><i>HTML</i></b> format
```

This is okay for the above example as it's small but when their is a lot of HTML code it's nearly impossible to read.  I can't figure out how to get Outlook to accept and show the HTML code.  Or how to copy past this somewhere to view.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This is a major problem experienced by others using Outlook. There are tips wherein you keep your formatting simple: as a rule, don't use any CSS elements. You can check this [blogpost](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how-to-code-emails-for-outlook-2016/) regarding workarounds to help you reduce HTML issue.

Comment: Well that sucks.  Can't find any other way to get the two systems to work together.  For viewing longer google notes in Outlook I've been able to use stackoverflow's question box to input the textual mess.  The preview window will translate it properly and then I simply don't submit.